# Variance of the median estimator of normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, estimation, order-statistics

I have some question.

> Let say we have sample with size $3$ from $N(\mu,\sigma)$ with known $\sigma$
> How can I calculate the Variance of the estimator $W(X_1,X_2,X_3)$?

What I've tried to do:

$$ \theta = \text{$p^{\text{th}}$ quantile of $X$ distribution}, \qquad 
p=\frac{k}{n+1} $$

For $f(\theta) \ne 0$:

$$ E[X_k] \approx \theta, \qquad \operatorname{Var}[X_k]\approx\frac{p(1-p)}{(n+2)(f(\theta))^2}$$

For the normal distribution: $p=0.5$, $\theta=\phi^{-1}(p)=\mu$, and

$$ \operatorname{Var[X_2]}
\approx\frac{0.25}{5\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{(\mu-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)^2}
=\frac{2\pi\sigma^2}{20}
\approx31.4
\quad !?$$

This is my R code, here I get something around 45.30

```
N=10000
n=3
mu=75
sigma=10
W2 = c(0,N)
c_var = c()
for (i in 1:N) {
    X=rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
    W2[i] = median(X)
    c_var = c(c_var, var(W2[1:i]))
    
}

plot(c_var, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "blue", ylab = "Oberved Var - Normal",
xlab = "Number of Obs",  main='Variance of median sample of Normal distribution')


print(var(W2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $Z_i = (X_i - \mu)/\sigma$ and noting that the order statistics satisfy $X_{(i)} = \mu + \sigma Z_{(i)}$, it suffices to study the variance of $Z_{(2)}$. Now, [it is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) that the PDF of $Z_{(2)}$ is given by

$$ f_{Z_{(2)}}(x) = 6\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x))\phi(x), $$

where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution, respectively. Now by noting that

$$ f_{-Z_{(2)}}(x) = f_{Z_{(2)}}(-x) = 6\Phi(-x)(1-\Phi(-x))\phi(-x) = 6(1-\Phi(x))\Phi(x)\phi(x) = f_{Z_{(2)}}(x), $$

it follows that the distribution of $Z_{(2)}$ is symmetric about $0$ and hence $ \mathbf{E}[Z_{(2)}] = 0 $. So, the variance of $Z_{(2)}$ is the same as $\mathbf{E}[Z_{(2)}^2]$. However, by utilizing the formula

$$ \int x \phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =- \phi(x) + \mathsf{C}, $$

which can be easily proved by u-substitution, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Var}(Z_{(2)})
&= \mathbf{E}[Z_{(2)}^2] \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 6x^2\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x))\phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 6 \bigl( x\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x)) \bigr)'\phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{$\because$ IbP} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigl( \underbrace{6 \Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x)) \phi(x)}_{=f_{Z_{(2)}}(x)} + \underbrace{6x\phi(x)^2}_{\text{odd}} - 12x\phi(x)^2\Phi(x) \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 1 + 0 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 12x\phi(x)^2\Phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

So it suffices to compute the last integral:

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 12x\phi(x)^2\Phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{6}{\sqrt{2}\pi^{3/2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2-y^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{ y \leq x \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{6}{\pi^{3/2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2-y^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{ \sqrt{2}y \leq x \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \tag{$y \mapsto \sqrt{2}y$} \\
&= \frac{6}{\pi^{3/2}} \biggl( \int_{\arctan(1/\sqrt{2})-\pi}^{\arctan(1/\sqrt{2})} \cos \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \biggr) \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} r^2 e^{-r^2} \, \mathrm{d}r \biggr)\\
&= \frac{6}{\pi^{3/2}} \biggl( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \biggr) \biggl( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \biggr) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}.
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$ \mathbf{Var}(Z_{(2)}) = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi} \approx 0.448671. $$

The following is a histogram for the $10^8$ simulated medians of $(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3)$ together with the summary statistics:

[image: histogram of simulated medians]

Here is the *Mathematica* code used to generate the above histogram:

```
(* Generate 10^8 samples *)
data=Table[
    Median[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],3]],
    {10^8}
];
(* Draw histogram *)
Labeled[
    Histogram[
        data,
        {Min[data],Max[data],0.2},
        "PDF",
        LabelStyle->Directive["Label",14],
        Epilog->{
        Text[Style[StringTemplate["Mean = `m`\nVar = `v`\nn = `n`"][<|
            "m"->ToString[NumberForm[Mean[data],{Infinity,4}]],
            "v"->ToString[NumberForm[Variance[data],{Infinity,4}]],
            "n"->"10^8"
            |>],14,TextAlignment->Left,"Label"],{Min[data]+0.1,0.62},{-1,1}]
        }
    ],
    {Style["Frequency",14],Style["Simulated median",14]},
    {Left,Bottom},
    RotateLabel->True
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! can you post here the code for the histogram?

Comment: I did it with R(I posted it now) and I get something aroung 45.30 while you got something aroung 0.448

Comment: @Amitn, That does not contradict my computation. Note that you are working with i.i.d. samples with $X_i\sim\mathcal(\mu,\sigma^2)$, whereas I am working with their standardizations $Z_i=(X_i-\mu)/\sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. So, in terms of the original samples, $$\mathbf{Var}(X_{(2)}) = \mathbf{Var}(\mu + \sigma Z_{(2)}) = \sigma^2 \mathbf{Var}(Z_{(2)}) = \sigma^2\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\right). $$ Since you chose $\sigma = 10$, your result is consistent with what the above identity predicts: $$\sigma^2\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\right) \approx 44.8671. $$